# Virtualbox cannot assign more than 4 cores (8 core host)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ubuntu-17.04

I have windows 10 host running virtualbox Version `5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2)`
And an Ubuntu 17.04 x64 guest with guest addition stuff.

The host has AMD 8 core cpu but I get a warning when assigning more than 4 cores to this VM. Would it really harm performance? why is that?

I have tried it in the past on older Ubuntu guest releases and it was the same issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the [answer](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=61945)

AMD says it is 8 core but it is actually 4 physical cores, or that's what Windows tells virtualbox anyway.

Comment: Under Linux host, the same virtualbox log:

```
CPUM: Logical host processors: 8 present, 8 max, 8 online, online mask: 00000000000000ff
CPUM: Physical host cores: 4
```